# App only works after Tomcat restart

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

i have a strange problem. I deploy a webapplication... the webapplication comes up without errors when i start the tomcat. But if i do a stop / start of the webapplication in the tomcat manager i receive a classnotfound exception...

Tomcat Startup Log:

```
2015-12-13 22:13:03 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
2015-12-13 22:13:16,466 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.c.ContextLoader | Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2015-12-13 22:13:16,761 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext | Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:13:16 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-13 22:13:16,911 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:17,381 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:17,441 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.s.c.SpringSecurityCoreVersion | You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.1.RELEASE
2015-12-13 22:13:17,455 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler | Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.0.1.RELEASE
2015-12-13 22:13:17,965 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.s.c.h.AuthenticationConfigBuilder | No login page configured. The default internal one will be used. Use the 'login-page' attribute to set the URL of the login page.
2015-12-13 22:13:17,977 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.s.c.h.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser | Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
2015-12-13 22:13:18,007 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:18,865 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-tx.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:18,920 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-couchdb.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:18,935 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-mail.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:18,945 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-jms.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:20,393 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean | Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-12-13 22:13:30,764 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain | Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2b0fabfa, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@70e6913d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@53ad62dc, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2235eed, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@54a56528, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@108e79f8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@280d42b7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3041a56d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4fb21a68, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2c90fbdf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6eca0c00, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@531db679, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@c238728, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2746cb70]
2015-12-13 22:13:31,691 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor | Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2015-12-13 22:13:31,701 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.c.ContextLoader | Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 15225 ms
2015-12-13 22:13:31,751 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet | FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
2015-12-13 22:13:31,756 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext | Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:13:31 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-13 22:13:31,756 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet-context.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:32,305 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Overriding bean definition for bean 'businessMaximizerStartup': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.mleitner.businessmaximizer.security.BusinessMaximizerStartup]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=1; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\maxi\WEB-INF\classes\com\mleitner\businessmaximizer\security\BusinessMaximizerStartup.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.mleitner.businessmaximizer.security.BusinessMaximizerStartup]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=1; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=init; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet-context.xml]]
2015-12-13 22:13:32,305 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler | Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.0.1.RELEASE
2015-12-13 22:13:32,335 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-rest.xml]
2015-12-13 22:13:33,640 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | c.m.b.s.BusinessMaximizerStartup | BusinessMaximizerStartup init called...
2015-12-13 22:13:33,705 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | c.m.b.s.AuthenticationDefaultSetup | AuthenticationDefaultSetup set up defaultusers...
2015-12-13 22:13:38,054 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping | Mapped <removed, because to big>
2015-12-13 22:13:38,521 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter | Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:13:31 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-13 22:13:38,661 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter | Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:13:31 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-13 22:13:38,721 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver | Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in laraGlobalExceptionHandler
2015-12-13 22:13:38,851 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor | Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2015-12-13 22:13:38,963 | INFO  | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet | FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 7212 ms
```

WebApp Stop / Start Log:

```
2015-12-13 22:14:20,971 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext | Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:13:31 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-13 22:14:20,976 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor | Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2015-12-13 22:14:21,436 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext | Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:13:16 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-13 22:14:21,436 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor | Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2015-12-13 22:14:21,446 | WARN  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor | Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'broker': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException
2015-12-13 22:14:21,451 | WARN  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter | Invocation of destroy method 'destroy' failed on bean with name 'broker': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException
2015-12-13 22:14:21,456 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-3 | o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean | Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-12-13 22:14:37,232 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.w.c.ContextLoader | Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2015-12-13 22:14:37,522 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext | Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Dec 13 22:14:37 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-13 22:14:37,667 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:38,037 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:38,069 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.s.c.SpringSecurityCoreVersion | You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.1.RELEASE
2015-12-13 22:14:38,079 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler | Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.0.1.RELEASE
2015-12-13 22:14:38,294 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.s.c.h.AuthenticationConfigBuilder | No login page configured. The default internal one will be used. Use the 'login-page' attribute to set the URL of the login page.
2015-12-13 22:14:38,304 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.s.c.h.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser | Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
2015-12-13 22:14:38,339 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:39,135 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-tx.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:39,185 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-couchdb.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:39,195 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-mail.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:39,205 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-jms.xml]
2015-12-13 22:14:40,440 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean | Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-12-13 22:14:49,729 | INFO  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain | Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@31a5e97c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1a82f575, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1092658, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@28a53e0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1c7ab4c4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@11dec363, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@592d0ce6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@9684170, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@407d080d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@27df0eba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@16a46c9b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5d8cdcfe, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@75999a22, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2a6cf0f5]
2015-12-13 22:14:50,126 | WARN  | http-nio-8080-exec-5 | o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'broker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at
```

Anybody an idea?

Env-Infos:

- Windows 7 OS
- Java 1.8.0_25
- Tomcat 8.0.30
- WebApp uses Spring, Active MQ, CouchDB, Hibernate ...
- Some libs like ActiveMQ are not packaged into the war-file. They are put into a separate folder. This folder is added to common.loader in catalina.properties
- Some config files are not packaged into the war-file. They are put into a separate folder. This folder is added to shared.loader.

Spring-Lib Details (all spring*.jar files):

- activemq-spring-5.13.0
- org.ektorp.spring-1.4.2
- spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-data-commons-1.10.0.RELEASE
- spring-data-jpa-1.8.2.RELEASE
- spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-security-config-4.0.1.RELEASE
- spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE
- spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE
- spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE
- xbean-spring-3.7

Catalina.properties (commented version works, but it's dirty):

```
#common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/bmstuff/lib","${catalina.home}/bmstuff/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/webapps/maxi/WEB-INF/lib","${catalina.home}/webapps/maxi/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar"

common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
server.loader=
shared.loader="${catalina.base}/bmstuff/","${catalina.base}/bmstuff/lib","${catalina.base}/bmstuff/lib/*.jar"
```

**Update - dirty solution found:**
I have found a dirty solution... if i add the lib folder of my webapplication in catalina properties to the common.loader, i can start and stop my webapplication without any errors..

KR

Comment: This looks like a symptom of a deeper problem. Something is failing to initialise but the NoClassDef error suggests an inconsistent set of Spring jars. Have you checked that all the Spring jars in your app are of the same version?

Comment: I have updated my initial post. Spring libs should be ok... may be there is a problem with this shared/common loader configuration what i did?

Comment: One more thing: If you have a look on the second log... already at the stop of the web app there is a warning at 2015-12-13 22:14:21,446 => NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Could it be a classloader problem?! Please check my last update in the initial post. Thank you.

Comment: It does seem like a classloader solution. Could there be some stray spring jars which have made it into your tomcat installation or classpath somehow?

Comment: I have no idea how this should be possible. It's a new tomcat installation, i just edited catalina.properties, added a jndi resource to the context.xml and create a folder for config + libs which are needed by the webapplication but which are not packaged into the .war file.

Answer (score 2):

At least two spring jars have amother version `4.0.9`:

- spring-orm
- spring-jdbc

`Spring Security` has it's own versioning, so that should be fine.

`Springg Data` I'm not sure, but could be fine.

Comment: I have fixed spring-orm and spring-jdbc dependecies. Thanks a lot for this hint. I created a new .war file, deployed it... still the same exception. If i do an undeploy, stop the tomcat, start the tomcat, deploy... web apps comes up without problems. I stop the webapp, start it again... exception like in initial post.